# Testing my JSON file and getting an "UnrecognizedPropertyException" Error in java

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm getting this error whilst reading my JSON file in a test class to see if it works, and I don't understand why. It's validated so there is nothing wrong with the JSON file. 
Any help would be appreciated thanks.

My test class:

```
public class ObjectToJsonFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    File file = new File("question.json");

    try {
        // Deserialize JSON file into Java object.
        Question question= mapper.readValue(file, Question.class);
        System.out.println("category.getCategory() = " + question.getCategory());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

My answer class looks like this:

```
public class Answer  
 {

@JsonProperty("answer")
private String answer;
@JsonProperty("correct")
private Boolean correct;
//setters and getters
}
```

My question class looks like this:
    public class Question {

```
@JsonProperty("category")
private String category;
@JsonProperty("clue")
private String clue;
@JsonProperty("Answers")
private List<Answer> answers;
@JsonProperty("questionTitle")
private String questionTitle;
//setters an getters
}
```

My questions class:

```
    public class Questions {

       @JsonProperty("Questions")
       private List<Questions> questions;


      @JsonCreator
      public Questions(List<Questions> questions) {
        super();
         this.questions = questions;
    }
// setters and getters
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a lot of small errors. Missing annotations, wrong field name case or confusing `Questions` with `Question` type in `main()`. I more or less fixed your code below, please see comments in the code below:

Answer:

```
public class Answer {

  @JsonProperty("answer")
  private String answer;
  @JsonProperty("Correct") // was "correct"
  private Boolean correct;
```

Questions:

```
public class Questions {

  @JsonProperty("Questions")
  private List<Question> questions;

  @JsonCreator
  public Questions(@JsonProperty("Questions") List<Question> questions) { // was missing @JsonProperty
    this.questions = questions;
  }
```

Main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
  File file = new File("question.json");

  try {
    Questions question = mapper.readValue(file, Questions.class); // was Question
    System.out.println("category.getCategory() = " + question.getQuestions().get(0).getCategory()); // corrected after changing to Questions
  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Comment: Now I also corrected the other errors. If I were you I'd avoid `@JsonProperty` and other forced overrides and instead changing the JSON to use camelCase fields.

Comment: Would you mind accepting the answer and upvoting? :)

Comment: Probably you would like to add another `Queston` object with different `category` value to the `Questions` array in JSON and then extract it in `main()` but your problem statement is a bit vague.

Comment: If you are on Java 8 you can use a Lambda to filter out your questions

`Questions root = mapper.readValue(file, Questions.class); List<Question> mathQuestions  = root.getQuestions().stream().filter(q -> q.getCategory().equals("math")).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: Not sure what do you mean by "my answer". Each questions has multiple `Answer` so I don't know which is "my".

Comment: Assuming you found the right `Question q` object and player said `nine` you could check with something like `q.getAnswers().stream().filter(a -> a.getAnswer().equals("nine")).findFirst().orElseThrow(IllegalArgumentException::new).getCorrect();`. It will throw an exception if `nine` is not a valid answer, error handling is something that depends on your requirements here.

Answer (score 1):

While you writes a java class for mapping of a json array, be very careful and verify each field which are going to be injected through setter methods. Your problem is in below codes. Just a small mistake you did.

```
   @JsonProperty("Questions")
   private List<Question> questions;//it should be Question object 


  @JsonCreator
  public Questions(List<Question> questions)//change the constructor accordingly
```

If you still get issues just check all in the possible injections whether correct or not.

GOOD LUCK!